# input string was not in correct format c# error

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have create an application where the information are based on what i have in the database.

When user type a code where that code exist in the database, the information will come out and fill up the remaining text-boxes.

Here is my database:

[image]

Here is the screenshot of my program when i type "**SM0001"**.

[image]

Notice that before i type "**SM0001**" in the "Product Code text-box", the "Quantity text-box", the "Description text-box", the "Sub Total text-box" and the "Total text-box" are empty.

When i type "**SM0001**" in the "Product Code text-box", it display all the data that belong to that code that i entered.

**Note: Price in the database is Sub Total in Program**

Here is my problem:
When i type "**SM0002**", in the "Product Code text-box" (That code that i entered is not in the database, the product code that have in the database only "**SM0001**"), the program stop and gave me the error "**Input string was not in correct format"**, and it is pointed at here:

```
price = Convert.ToDecimal(this.numericTextBox2.Text);
```

Here is the necessary code:

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdatePrice(sender, e);
        }

private void UpdatePrice(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal quantity = 0;
            decimal price = 0;
            int total = 0;

            if (numericTextBox1.TextLength == 6)
            {
                this.numericUpDown1.Enabled = true;

                quantity = Convert.ToInt32(this.numericUpDown1.Value);
                price = Convert.ToDecimal(this.numericTextBox2.Text);
                total = Convert.ToInt32(quantity * price);

                if (numericUpDown1.Value > 0)
                {
                    this.numericTextBox3.Text = total.ToString();
                }
            }

            else if (numericTextBox1.TextLength != 6)
            {
                this.numericUpDown1.Enabled = false;

                this.textBox5.Text = "";
                this.numericUpDown1.Value = 0;
                this.numericTextBox2.Text = "";
                this.numericTextBox3.Text = "";
            }

            else
            {
                quantity = 0;
                price = 0;
                total = 0;

                MessageBox.Show("There is no data based on your selection", "Error");
            }
```

Could anyone help me please?

"Product Code text-box is NumericTextBox1", "Sub Total text-box is NumericTextBox2", and "Total text-box is NumericTextBox3"

Comment: It would really help if you'd name your text boxes as to *meaning* instead of `numericTextBox1`, `numericTextBox2` etc. The fact that within a condition about `numericTextBox1.Length` you don't actually use `numericTextBox1` at all is deeply suspicious, but we don't know which text box corresponds to which variable. Is `numericTextBox1` the text box which is being typed in? Because if so, you'd have set `numericTextBox2.Text` to "" when the previous character was typed. At the moment your question is too hard to follow to really help you...

Answer (score 5):

If your exception is here

```
price = Convert.ToDecimal(this.numericTextBox2.Text);
```

and your product code SM0002 doesnot exists, then this means you are parsing a value that doesnot exists. So in that case you some handling mechanism.

Use TryParse , with this you can handle any non-parsable value and return desired value.
You can use this method:

```
private double ParseDouble(string value)
{
  double d=0;
  if(!double.TryParse(value , out d))
  {
      return 0;
  }
  return d;
}
```

so your code should look like, where ever conversion is required.

```
var price = ParseDouble(numericTextBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

before convert check it null or empty 
like

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.numericTextBox2.Text.ToString()))
{
price = Convert.ToDecimal(this.numericTextBox2.Text);
}else
{
price = 0;//or what you want
}
```